# Not able to Bind Data from services to Ionic

Tags: json, symfony, ionic-framework

Hi I want to bind data which is coming from symfony Back-end  as json response, as follows.

**Controller**

```
app.controller('DashboardCtrl',function($scope,$state,DashBoardServices) {

$scope.allChilds = [];

$scope.getAllChildDetails = function($http) {

    DashBoardServices.getAllChild("57cd019afbe0855c0e8b4568")
        .then(function (response) {

            $scope.allChilds = response.data;
            //grant access to the app
            if(response.data.MessageId == 1) {                    
                $state.go("child");//want to list all child data in this template
            }else{
                $state.go("dash");
            }

        });
}
});
```

**Services**

```
app.factory('DashBoardServices', function($http) {

 return {
         getAllChild: function (parentId) {
         return $http.post('http://127.1.1.0:8080/EduboldPortalApp/eduboldportal/web/app_dev.php/api/all/child', {
         parentId: parentId

         });
         }
});
```

**Json response**

```
{
"MessageId": 1,
"data": [{
    "parentId": "57cd019afbe0855c0e8b4568",
    "id": {
        "$id": "57ccffd2fbe085880c8b4567"
    },
    "firstName": "PRATHAMVEER",
    "middleName": "SINGH",
    "lastName": "CHAHAL"
}, {
    "parentId": "57cd019afbe0855c0e8b4568",
    "id": {
        "$id": "57cd019afbe0855c0e8b4567"
    },
    "firstName": "GUNSHEEN",
    "middleName": "KAUR",
    "lastName": "CHAHAL"
}]
}
```

I have a template called: **allChild.html** where I want to list all the child as follows:

```
  <ion-content>
        <div class="list">
            <a ng-repeat="chd in allChilds"   class="item item-thumbnail-left">
           {{chd.firstName}}               

        </a>
</ion-content>
```

But its not rendering data, Please help I am just started to use Ionic..

thanks in advance

Comment: Which controller use for "allChild.html"?  Call service on that contoller.

OR

Use to pass data to "allChild.html"  by : $state.go("child",{obj:yourObj}); and get as "$stateParams" in controller

Comment: controller is same : DashboardCtrl

Comment: I am trying as:
  $scope.allChilds = response.data;
                //grant access to the app
                if(response.data.MessageId == 1) {
                    //$state.go("child");
                    $state.go("child",{obj:$scope.allChilds});
                }else{
                    $state.go("back");
                }

Comment: Can you please assist me in this, still I m not getting data in allChild.html

Comment: @SunilRawat Are you getting data to $scope.allChilds in this stage `code  DashBoardServices.getAllChild("57cd019afbe0855c0e8b4568")
        .then(function (response) {

            $scope.allChilds = response.data;
            //grant access to the app
            if(response.data.MessageId == 1) {                    
                $state.go("child");//want to list all child data in this template
            }else{
                $state.go("dash");
            }

        });` ?

Comment: yes,can you please check it what could be the issue

Comment: I am getting data in response variable: as

.then(function (response) {

$scope.allChilds = response.data;
}